# Custom functions inexplicably stop working for certain values

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have defined two functions, sPad and zPad, for use in google spreadsheets, to append +'s (as spaces for a url) and prepend zeroes, respectively, until the resulting string is the specified length. When I first defined the functions, they seemed to work fine, but then I shared the spreadsheet and it's now arbitrarily refusing to load results. This is the second time this has happened. Making the spreadsheet private again did not resolve the issue.

```
function sPad(string, length) {
  string = string.toString();
  if (string.length >= length) {
      return string;
  } else {
      return string + Array(length - string.length + 1).join("+");
  }
};

function zPad(number, length) {
  number = number.toString();
  if (number.length >= length) {
      return number;
  } else {
      return Array(length - number.length + 1).join("0") + number;
  }
};
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DQPBCOdIaU7tZz6ukb2upxqmJU9P8ag6jFU50oNftpU/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT: Whether or not the results actually load seems to happen on a coin flip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are getting the indefinite "Loading..." error from time to time. It seems to be observed mainly when open-ended ranges are passed as parameters, but in your case, you are passing two single values.

[This is the best thread that I can find](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=custom%20function&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=3891) for the issue; you might like to star it as a way of (kind of) voting for it, and also be notified of updates.

Making an edit on the formula, or the underlying data being passed to it, seems to generally resolve the issue. Another workaround is not to use custom functions, and process using either native functions (which would be possible with your particular examples), or using gets and sets in Google Apps Script, perhaps run on an onEdit trigger. Obviously, it would be ideal not to have to resort to these workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was hoping that I just missed something, as this is the first time that I've made a custom function.